# Efficient in-memory storage of 8,000,000 records (Python)

Tags: python, hbase, thrift, in-memory-database

I have a database of person records that I need to load into memory, since they will be accessed many times in a variety of orders. Up until now I've just instantiated one Python object per record. But now that I have 8,000,000 records to work with, I don't have enough memory for this straightforward approach.

In a flat file, each record only takes up at most 500 bytes, without compression (much less with compression). So the whole dataset is less than 4 GB on disk. Once each record is loaded by Python as an object, however, I estimate 40 GB of RAM will be used. My machine only has 12 GB of RAM.

I'm considering integrating C with my Python program, and storing each record as a struct in C. Does this sound like a good solution? Or is there a better way to store records compactly in Python, that doesn't require interfacing with C?

**Update:** The database I'm using is Hbase (http://hbase.apache.org/), running on Hadoop. The connection to Python  happens through Thrift (http://thrift.apache.org/).

**Update 2:** I need to access all the records in the database in many different orders, and these orders are determined at run time. I guess, at every iteration, I could make 8,000,000 queries to the database, but I think this is likely to be quite slow.

**Update 3:** I don't think there's a good way to store the rows, such that they can be accessed sequentially. The order in which I need the records in the next iteration (my program is an iterative machine learning algorithm), is determined by a linear algebra projection onto a particular eigenvector of the data matrix during the previous iteration.

Comment: Isn't the point of most databases that you don't have to store your data in memory?

Comment: What is your database? Why do you need to load into memory?

Comment: Yeah, what is the point of dumping the entire db into memory?

Comment: When you say database- do you mean it's stored in a database like SQL or MongoDB? Or do you mean that it's a dataset in the form of a large tab-delimited or comma-separated file?

Comment: Loading up all of the records on one physical server doesn't seem like a great idea...

Comment: What kind of non-sequential orders? It's likely much easier to make your queries work with Hbase or another database than to read *everything* into memory in some kind of compact format. Furthermore, what happens when your number of records becomes even greater?

Comment: Have you looked into `__slots__` on the class that stores a record of data?  That should make your objects more memory efficient at the expense of flexability.

Comment: What type of data do you get from the database ? If it's for a ML algorithm, you should only need numerical values, and thus I would recommend to see numpy and store everything in matrices (stored as raw C arrays)

Comment: @mgilson: `__slots__` works really well...just reduced my memory usage by 50% by adding it to my "person record" class.

Comment: @Jeff -- Glad to hear it :).  It's amazing how much extra space those silly class dictionaries take ;^).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like numpy [structured arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) could work well here. It will use a lot less memory than using python objects and numpy provides many fast & convenient operations on them. Additionally, the arrays can be memory mapped files which can be useful sometimes.

Whether or not a database is a good option (as others suggest) depends on your algorithm as well as data sizes. There are many cases where numpy is a better solution (less work, more efficient, etc.).

Comment: It seems like numpy's structured arrays are about as memory efficient as structs is C, so this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use case for a database. Instead of storing everything in memory, you can store it on disk and query it as you like.

[sqllite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) is one good and easy option. You might be particularly interested in an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) such as [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), which makes working with databases similar to working with Python objects.

Comment: Actually, SQLite _can_ work with [in-memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), so it covers that requirement as well.

Comment: @lanzz: True, but I assumed the database was too large for that to be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a lot of ways to handle this depending on the desired performance and use cases, but you probably don't really need to have all data in memory. One obvious way to go is using a real database engine like [`sqlite`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) or [`mysql`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/). A simpler-to-implement, but probably much  slower way is [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html).

Comment: Actually I have found shelve to be much faster for certain use cases (num reads >>> num writes) -- with the added cost of the data being restricted to a single machine

Comment: It's worth noting that shelve doesn't allow concurrent write and read/write access. If you are looking for something that's going to be written to concurrently (threads or processes), shelve is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others in that thread that a database would be the tool of choice, but if you insist on in memory have a lookt at http://www.memsql.com/ (though I have never worked with it)